# Deleting images after new image was selected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have got a few buttons which users can select and it will display an image, however it seems to stack the images on top of each other and not deleting the previous image.  I have found a similar question here but it still doesn't seem to work.

here is my Complete code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SlidingDrawer;

public class Samples extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
    setContentView(R.layout.samples);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    final SlidingDrawer slider = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.sD2);
    slider.animateOpen();

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.samplea);
    Button next1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sampleb);
    Button next2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.samplec);
    Button next3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sampled);
    Button next4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.samplee);
    Button next5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.samplef);
    Button next6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sampleg);
    Button next7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sampleh);
    Button next8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.samplei);
    Button next9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.samplej);
    Button next10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.samplek);
    Button next11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.samplel);
    Button next12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.samplem);
    Button next13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.samplen);



    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // You can turn this into a class variable
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iM2);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.samplea);
            slider.animateClose();
        }
    });

   next1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iM2);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sampleb);

        slider.animateClose();
        } 
    });

    next2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iM2);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.samplec);
        slider.animateClose();
        } 
    });

    next3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iM2);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sampled);
        slider.animateClose();
        } 
    });

    next4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iM2);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.samplee);
        slider.animateClose();
        } 
    });

    next5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iM2);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.samplef);
        slider.animateClose();
        } 
    });

    next6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iM2);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sampleg);
        slider.animateClose();
        } 
    });

    next7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iM2);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sampleh);
        slider.animateClose();
        } 
    });

    next8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iM2);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.samplei);
        slider.animateClose();
        } 
    });

    next9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iM2);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.samplej);
        slider.animateClose();
        } 
    });

    next10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iM2);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.samplek);
        slider.animateClose();
        } 
    });

    next11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iM2);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.samplel);
        slider.animateClose();
        } 
    });

    next12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iM2);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.samplem);
        slider.animateClose();
        } 
    });


    next13.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iM2);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.samplen);
        slider.animateClose();

        }
    });
        }
    }
```

and for xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <RelativeLayout 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iM2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/sD2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Sample" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="@drawable/sampleshd">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/samplea"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/sampleabutton" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/sampleb"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/samplea"
                    android:background="@drawable/samplebbutton" 
                    android:longClickable="true"/>
```

It just repeats for all the other buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set any background in your xml for this imageView? Because background and src(imageResource) are different... So if you set image's background in your xml and if you're setting its resource in your java code, yes you may see more than one image.

Comment: Have added my xml code.  Just to be sure does this code work, the reason I am asking aswell is that when i test this app on my samsung gs2 (ICS) and samsung young (version 2 or 3 i think) it works fine.  But on my 10.1 inch tablet after selecting a few images or selecting variuos other things i have in the app it says the that the app has stopped working and returns to my homescreen on the tablet? (Tablet, android version is 4.0.4)

Comment: Ok, according to your xml and you're saying it's not what i thought... But if you got that error after selecting some images correctly, most likely you got a  memory leak. Try to check with MAT.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply,  I have added the errors i get from testing the app on my tablet, above in my original question.

Comment: Ok, so it says that you have a OutOfMemoryError indeed. But i cannot say what you need to do without seeing your code. You need to search on this situation. You can dumb your code with MAT and analyze it.

Comment: Thanks, although i have never used MAT, so how do i go about it?

Comment: First of all, you can do some googling about it because there are lots of topics... I'm pretty sure that there are lots of good answered questions in stackoverflow itself too. Or else, you can share more code here, and i can check if i could find your memory leak...

Comment: Do you just want the code for the java class as posted above in my question?

Comment: Sorry to reply this late. I haven't seen anything that can cause memory leak, but of course i may overlook. But can you try to find your imageview once like your slider, then set only it's resource on click.

Comment: I have done what you said and it seemed to work great for about 10 minutes of testing then gives me a error.  but on my samsung gs2 it works fine with no problems what so ever. Could it be my tablet? or could it be my codes? I appreciate all your help! (update: on my tablet it seems to give me a error just randomly during testing of app)

Comment: Ok, so glad to here that helps... You can, of course, do some improvements. But for now, i've got no more idea. So far, it's working now, i guess you can accept my answer right?